# Shorter way to select latest package path using Powershell

Tags: powershell

The aim is to select the path to the latest package. Although the code works, there should be a shorter way.

**Paths**

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Childitem "C:\google\*\SDK Manager.exe" | % { $_.FullName } | Sort-Object eventid -descending
C:\google\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\SDK Manager.exe
C:\google\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130702\SDK Manager.exe
```

**Select latest package path**

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Childitem "C:\google\*\SDK Manager.exe" | % { $_.FullName } | Sort-Object eventid -descending | Select-Object -first 1
C:\google\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\SDK Manager.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is an eventid to sort on `Sort-Object eventid -descending`? Is that a mistake? Sort-Object wont throw and error if the what you are sorting on does not exist.

Are you looking for brevity?

```
(Get-ChildItem "C:\google\*\SDK Manager.exe").FullName | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

which could be shortened using aliases to:

```
(gci "C:\google\*\SDK Manager.exe").FullName | sort -Descending | Select -first 1
```